# How to unkey the Office product 2013 through batch file

Tags: microsoft-office

I have tried with batch file to unkey the office product but it is just appearing command prompt, not performing command that I have given.

Please find the below command and correct me

`SETLOCAL SET PATH "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15" START "Unkey" CMD.EXE "cscript ospp.vbs /unpkey:xxxxx"`

I tried this command as well

`SETLOCAL SET PATH "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15" START "Unkey" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15" CMD.EXE "cscript ospp.vbs /unpkey:xxxxx"`

Comment: should just be a one liner: `cscript "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\OSPP.VBS" /unpkey:xxxxx`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set path="%path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15"
cscript ospp.vbs /unpkey:xxxxx
```

Save this as a .bat file and then run it.

- Never overwrite PATH, it will bring disaster
- Only CSCRIPT is enough for executing the VBS file, No need of calling START command

Comment: Thank you, it is working. But it is asking for admin privileges. Any idea how to run command prompt as admin through batch file?

Comment: Before running the batch file, right click it and click Run as administrator. If an UAC prompt comes then confirm it and provide Administrative credentials if needed.